# The program that I wrote doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows

I am a new programmer. I wrote a little program in python that writes a paragraph based on user input. I then converted it to .exe using auto-py-to-exe. The program works great on my Windows 10 pc. However, when I try and run it on a Windows 7 machine, it opens and closes immediately.

Is there a setting in Pycharm or auto-py-to-exe that I need to change to make it run?

I will paste my code below incase that's the issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
def main():
## Q1 In what condition is the book? ##
print("""
Q1. In what condition is the book?

1= As New 
2= Very Good 
3= Good 
4= Poor 
5= Working copy 
""")

A1 = input(">>")

if (A1 == "1"):
    A1 = "As New – "

if (A1 == "2"):
    A1 = "Very good condition – "

if (A1 == "3"):
    A1 = "Good condition – "

if (A1 == "4"):
    A1 = "Poor condition – "

if (A1 == "5"):
    A1 = "Working copy – "

## Q2 Is the book hard cover or soft cover? ##
print("""
Q2. Is the book hard cover or soft cover?

1= Hard Cover
2= Soft Cover
""")

A2 = input(">>>")

if (A2 == "1"):
    A2 = "Hard Cover. "

if (A2 == "2"):
    A2 = "Soft Cover. "

## Q3 How’s the binding on the book? ##
print("""
Q3. How’s the binding on the book?

1= Tightly Bound
2= Loose
""")

A3 = input(">>>")

if (A3 == "1"):
    A3 = "The book is tightly bound. "

if (A3 == "2"):
    A3 = "The binding is loose. "

## Q4 Are the pages foxed? ##
print("""
Q4.Are the pages foxed?

1= No Foxing (neat and clean)
2= Foxing on the pages
3= Foxing on the edges
4= Foxing on the pages and edges
""")

A4 = input(">>>")

if (A4 == "1"):
    A4 = "The pages are neat and clean. "

if (A4 == "2"):
    A4 = "Some of the pages are foxed. "

if (A4 == "3"):
    A4 = "The edges of the book are foxed. "

if (A4 == "4"):
    A4 = "The pages and edges of this book are foxed. "

## Q5 Does the previous owner's name appear in the book? ##
print("""
Q5. Does the previous owner's name appear in the book? 

1= Yes
2= No
""")

A5 = input(">>>")

if (A5 == "1"):
    A5 = "The previous owner's name is written in the book. "

if (A5 == "2"):
    A5 = ""

## Q6 Has the cover been damaged or scuffed? ##
print("""
Q6. Has the cover/spine been scuffed or faded?

1= No (Virtually undamaged)
2= The cover has been scuffed.
3= The cover is faded.
4= The cover is scuffed and faded.
5= The spine is faded.
""")

A6 = input(">>>")

if (A6 == "1"):
    A6 = "The cover is virtually undamaged. "

if (A6 == "2"):
    A6 = "The cover is scuffed. "

if (A6 == "3"):
    A6 = "The cover is faded. "

if (A6 == "4"):
    A6 = "The cover is scuffed and faded. "

if (A6 == "5"):
    A6 = "The spine of the book is faded. "

## Q7 In what condition is the Dust cover? ##
print("""
Q7. In what condition is the Dust cover? 

1= N/A
2= virtually undamaged.
3= Damaged.
""")

A7 = input(">>>")

if (A7 == "1"):
    A7 = ""
if (A7 == "2"):
    A7 = "The dust cover is virtually undamaged."

if (A7 == "3"):
    A7 = "The dust cover is damaged."

## Output Code##

print(A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6 + A7)

## Copy Code ##
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6 + A7)

## Exit Code ##

input("Press enter to exit ;)")

R1 = input("Repeat program?>>> ")

if (R1 == "r"):
    main()
```

main()

Comment: btw, you don't need parentheses for if statements in python

Comment: did you `pip install pyperclip` in Win 7 system?

Comment: I didn't check if pyperclip was installed on it. I'll check. Thanks for answering.